# Top 1 not return null

Tags: t-sql

I want to select top 1 value either null or value from this query

```
select top 1 column5 from table2 where table2.column1ID = 5
```

if the whole value of this column is null the return is empty , but I need to return value or null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your select in another select.

```
select
  (
  select top 1 column5 
  from table2 
  where table2.column1ID = 5
  --order by ?
  ) as column5
```